# How do I split string between From text.charAt() till space occurs in java?

Tags: java

How do I split string between From text.charAt(9) till next space occurs in java?

jhb 9jb 38888 hjbhjb7868hgvhv

I need to extact 38888

Comment: Do you mean `text.charAt(9)`, or the ninth character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

`String text = "jhb 9jb 38888 hjbhjb7868hgvhv";
 String subStrings[]=text.split(" ");
 System.out.println(subString[2]);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substring` method twice.

- First, get substring from 9th character (till the end of the String)
- Get another substring from 0 to index of the first whitespace, for the String retrieved in above step

`String  s = "jhb 9jb 38888 hjbhjb7868hgvhv";
 String subString = s.substring(8);
 System.out.println(subString.substring(0, subString.indexOf(" ")));`

Comment: Why twice? You could just do it once.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
String s = "jhb 9jb 38888 hjbhjb7868hgvhv";
System.out.println(s.substring(8, s.length()).split(" ")[0]);
```

Just takes a substring, and then splits it.

Answer (score 0):

Find the first occurrence of the ninth character:

```
// If you actually mean the ninth character, pos = 9.
int pos = text.indexOf(text.charAt(9));
```

Find the next space:

```
int nextSpace = text.indexOf(' ', pos);
```

Then take the substring between them:

```
String part = text.substring(pos, nextSpace);
```

Note that you may need to handle the case where no space follows, so `nextSpace == -1`.